# Calculating the distance between 2 given points

Tags: java, class, distance

I have to create a class to calculate the distance between 2 given points for class. The instructor gave us the top half of the assignment with all the necessary code without modifying, the problem that im having is creating the class part. This is what i have so far...

```
class Point{
int x;
int y;

public Point(){
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;

}

public Point(int x, int y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
 public double distance(int x, int y) {
    double d = Math.sqrt( Math.pow(x2-x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2-y1, 2) );
    return distance;
}
}
```

the top half of the assignment looks like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


class Assignment4{
public static void main(String[] args){
    // first and second points
    Point first, second;

    // try parsing points from command line args
    if(args.length==4){
        // new Point(int x, int y) creates a new Point located at position (x,y)
        first = new Point(Integer.valueOf(args[0]), Integer.valueOf(args[1]));
        second = new Point(Integer.valueOf(args[2]), Integer.valueOf(args[3]));
    }

    // if not specified as argument, get points from user
    else{
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter first point: ");
        first = new Point(input.nextInt(),input.nextInt());

        System.out.println("Enter second point: ");
        second = new Point(input.nextInt(),input.nextInt());
    }

    //calculate distance
    //double d = Math.sqrt( Math.pow(x2-x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2-y1, 2) );
    double d = first.distance(second.x, second.y);

    System.out.println("Distance between " + 
        "(" + first.x + "," + first.y + ")" + 
        " and " + 
        "(" + second.x + "," + second.y + ")" + 
        " is " + d);
    System.out.println();
}
}
```

When i try and compile the program, it says "cannot find symbol" referring to x2, x1, y2, y1, and distance.

Comment: @ChthonicProject Not really--`distance()` is an instance method, and it's trying to compute the distance between the current `Point`, and a point whose coordinates are given by the two arguments.

Comment: Was the definition of `distance`, i.e. `public double distance(int x, int y)`, given to you as part of the assignment, or was it your idea?  I'm just wondering why the method has to take `x` and `y` instead of another `Point`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here :

```
class Point{
     int x;
     int y;

     .....
     .....

     public double distance(int x, int y) {
        double d = Math.sqrt( Math.pow(x2-x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2-y1, 2) );  //ERROR IN THIS LINE
        return distance; //ERROR HERE TOO...(2)
     }
}
```

There is no x1,x2,y1,y2 defined in the class or in the method parameter.

Swap it with the following line:

> double d = Math.sqrt( Math.pow(this.x-x, 2) + Math.pow(this.y-y, 2) );

(2)
Error 2 Swap with this line:

> return d;

Comment: thanks! this helped a lot. but when i use this fixed portion, i get another error relating to: 

 first = new Point(Integer.valueOf(args[0]), Integer.valueOf(args[1]));
        second = new Point(Integer.valueOf(args[2]), Integer.valueOf(args[3]));
    }

ill get the detailed error info when im able to run it at home

Comment: sure no problem :). I don't understand what you said about fixed portion and I don't see why that portion of the code would give an error if you pass it valid parameters. Send me the error message then I can help you.